# footnote inside csquotes' blockquote: fails if microtype is loaded

Tags: footnotes, microtype, csquotes

The following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\blockquote{foo\footnote{bar.}.}
\end{document}
```

compiles like a charm but it is not the case anymore if `% \usepackage{microtype}` is uncommented, the error being:

```
! Package csquotes Error: Unbalanced groups or invalid nesting.

See the csquotes package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.37 \blockquote{foo\footnote{bar.}.}
                                     
?
```

the culprit being the embedded footnote. Note that, in the past, this was working as expected.

What's going on?

Comment: this is already fixed in the [dev version](https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/tree/dev)

Comment: ... and now also in the current version 3.0e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

microtype now patches  various commands to inject protrusion and they can fail in various places.

The typical workaround it to disable the patch (either make an educated guess or disable all patches) and then to report the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[nopatch=footnote]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\blockquote{foo\footnote{bar.}.}
\end{document}
```